Do I need a keyfile (for auto mount) if both my encrypted boot drive and encrypted secondary drive have the same password?
I'm on Ubuntu 24.04
So, my boot drive has LUKS full disk encryption and my secondary drive is encrypted using LUKS as well, they both have the same password. I'm trying to get my secondary drive to auto mount on log in and well, on Reddit, someone told me that since both my boot drive and secondary drive are using the same password I don't need a keyfile, here's what this person said to me.
Person on Reddit: You don't need a key file, if you set the password the same as your boot drive then you'll still only have to enter it once.
You do need to do the fstab and crypttab setup but these can be handled easily in the GUI these days, no real need to mess with them manually.
Me: Which GUI and can you tell me exactly how to do it or point me to a tutorial? And I do appreciate the help btw. But yeah I'm a newbie so I really do need step by step instructions on how to do this.
Person on Reddit: Sure, the one I am familiar with is "Disks" which is part of the GNOME suite of applications, I'm on Fedora KDE.
First choose the secondary device from the list on the left. On the right you should see the LUKS layer on top and then your data volume underneath.
Choose the LUKS layer and then click the little arrow button in the bottom left, Edit Encryption Options. Disable User Session Defaults, check "unlock at system startup". Don't need to enter the passphrase here, if you set it the same as your boot drive then it will automatically unlock at the same time anyway.
Then select the storage volume underneath, and click the little arrow again. Disable User Session Defaults, check "Mount at system startup", then set the mount point to the name you want.
That should be all you need to do. You can also encrypt drives with LUKS using this same application.
End.
So is it true that I don't need a keyfile since both my boot drive and secondary drive are using the same password, is it true that I can just do this using gnome disks?
And yeah I already know how to do this using a keyfile, it's just, someone told me on Reddit that in my particular case I actually don't need a keyfile so is that true?
